# A very simple question about Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

> Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ a measure space and let $\{f_n\}$ a sequence of measurable function and $f$ a measurable function, such that $\lim_ {n\to \infty} f_n(x)=f(x)$ a.e. in $X$. Suppose that exists a function $g\in L^1(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ such that $$|f_n|\le g\quad\text{a.e in}\;X.$$ Then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{X}|f_n-f|\;d\mu=0.$$

I have already shown what I have just said. Now I must proved that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_Xf_n d\mu=\int_X f d\mu.$$
I do this 
$$\color{BLUE}{\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_Xf_n\ d\mu}-\int_Xf d\mu\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg|\int_X(f_n-f)d\mu\bigg|\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X|f_n-f|d\mu=0$$

> > **Question** How do I know if the blue limit exists? Is it clear from what was said previously or is this procedure wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$|\int f_n d\mu -\int fd\mu| \leq \int |f_n-f| d\mu  \to 0$. So $\lim \int f_n d\mu$ exists and equals $\int f d\mu$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you could be more explicitly, still don't understand.

Comment: @JackJ. Start with the inequality in my answer for fixed $n$. (Don't start with $\lim \int f_n$ because you don't know that it exists). Now if $\epsilon >0$ there exists $n_o$ such that RHS $<\epsilon$ for all $n \geq n_0$. Hence LHS $<\epsilon$ for all $n \geq n_0$. This is exactly what we want to prove.